# How to get the route parameter in the VueJs 3 composition Api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I need a route parameter in a VueJS componente. For example the **42** in `example.de/page/42`.

```js
// router
// ...
    {
      path: '/pages/:id',
      name: 'pages',
      component: () => import('../views/PageView.vue'),

    },  
// ...
```

```js
// PageView.vue
<script setup>
    import { onMounted } from "vue";
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    onMounted(async () => {
      console.log(  $route.params.id );
   }
```

Here I get the error:
`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $route is not defined`.

But in template of the component the access with `{{ $route.params.id }}` is possible. But I need it in the script. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the composable function `useRoute` :

```js
   import { onMounted } from "vue";
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
   
   const route = useRoute()

    onMounted(async () => {
      console.log(route.params.id );
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps :-)  But I wonder why I have access to the params in the template and not in the script. Because then I have two variables with the router params in the memory that are redudant. Or not? Design fault? Best Max

Comment: You're welcome, using `$route` is a helper in options API, useRoute is for composition API, template has access to both APIs

Answer (score 5):

You need to import the useRoute and then you can access

```
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
```

and then create route.

```
const route =useRoute()
```

Comment: Thank you too! It was helpfull! I have one question regarding to this topic. Maybe you can help me.   But I wonder why I have access to the params in the template and not in the script. Because then I have two variables with the router params in the memory that are redudant. Or not? Design fault? Best Max